# Android Studio 3.2 Add Image Of Custom Size (not icon)

Tags: android, android-studio

When I right-click the Drawable folder and click New -> Image Asset, I'm presented with only four options: action and tab bar icons, launcher icons, launcher icons (legacy), and notification icons.

What if I want to add an image to just use in my app (not as a tiny icon)? Selecting any of the options above causes Android Studio to scale the image down to like 24x24dp when I want to display it at 100x100dp. So, when I display it, it looks really blurry. Why isn't there an option to add an image asset that's not tiny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limited modification is to comply with the material design specification. you could use **vector asset** if you want to get different size image.

[image]

and notice you should down image with `SVG` format, read the [ref in here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources)

another way is using thrid party plugins like [Android Drawable Importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer), which is flexiable and simpler.

Comment: It seems like this is the best solution so I accepted your answer. Unfortunately, in my case, the xml path string generated from my svg was too long for Java to compile so I am still stuck. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the image to your `drawable` folder in the Android sidebar view. Make sure it goes into `drawable` and not one of the density-dependent folders, and you'll have an image with a custom size.

Be aware that images can't be too big in Android. It shouldn't be larger than 1600px in either dimension, otherwise you run the risk of a laggy interface or an OutOfMemory error.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I would have done this, but I was worried about the memory issue; it seems like maybe using an SVG is a better but more complex solution.

Comment: It should be **larger than 1600px**?!